# Reconnect to server using connection state changed in signalr using android dynamically?

Tags: android, signalr

Am new for signal r and android development. I have successfully implement the working hub between android and server.  But am facing one problem during when connection state change eg(need to connect with server after internet connection  is available) while staying in that activity how can i achieve that here let me post my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements StateChangedCallback{
    private final Context mContext = this;
    private SignalRService mService;
    HubConnection conn;
     HubProxy chat;
    SignalRFuture<Void> connect ;
    private boolean mBound = false;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        Platform.loadPlatformComponent(new AndroidPlatformComponent());
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,SignalRService.class);
        startService(intent);
        intent.setClass(mContext, SignalRService.class);
        bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

        configConnectFuture();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // Unbind from the service
        Log.d("onstop","onstop");
        if (mBound) {
            unbindService(mConnection);
            mBound = false;
        }
        super.onStop();
    }
    public void Send_Click(View view)
    {
        final HubConnectionFactory hcf = HubConnectionFactory.getInstance();
        conn = hcf.getHubConnection();
        final HubProxy chat = hcf.getChatHub();
        chat.invoke("send", "android says", "hello!").done(new Action<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void run(Void obj) throws Exception {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    /*private void startSignalR() {
        Platform.loadPlatformComponent(new AndroidPlatformComponent());
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Start", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        String server = "http://172.16.6.106:8080/ChatRoomApplication/";
        HubConnection connection = new HubConnection(server);
        HubProxy proxy = connection.createHubProxy("ChatHub");
        ClientTransport clientTransport = new ServerSentEventsTransport(connection.getLogger());
        SignalRFuture<Void> awaitConnection = connection.start(clientTransport);
        try {
           awaitConnection.get();
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        proxy.invoke("Send", "Yoge","Yoges");


    }*/


    private void configConnectFuture() {
        final HubConnectionFactory hcf = HubConnectionFactory.getInstance();
        connect=  hcf.connect("http://172.16.6.106:8080/SignalRChat/");
        conn = hcf.getHubConnection();
        chat = hcf.getChatHub();
        conn.stateChanged(this);
        final LongPollingTransport transport = new LongPollingTransport(conn.getLogger()); // Works on WiFi, never connects on 3G, no error is thrown either
        //ClientTransport transport = new WebsocketTransport(mConnection.getLogger()); // Never connects, not error is thrown
        connect= conn.start(transport);
        try {
            connect.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        conn.reconnecting(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

            }
        });
        this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
 connect.onError(new ErrorCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onError(final Throwable error) {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                connect.triggerError(error);
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
               FloatingActionButton fab=(FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab);
                fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Log.d("onclick","onclick");
                        chat.invoke("Send", "Yogesh Says", "Magizhchi!").done(new Action<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void run(Void obj) throws Exception {
                                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
                                    public void run() {
                                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });



                chat.on("broadcastMessage", new SubscriptionHandler2<String, String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void run(final String p1, final String p2) {
                        Log.d("Signalr", "Name := " + p1 +" Msg:="+p2);

                    }
                }, String.class, String.class);

                conn.closed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Log.e("closed","close");
                        conn.disconnect();
                           new reconnectPulling().execute();
                    }
                });

                conn.connected(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Log.d("connected","connected");
                        chat.on("broadcastMessage", new SubscriptionHandler2<String, String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void run(final String p1, final String p2) {
                                Log.d("Signalr", "Name := " + p1 +" Msg:="+p2);
                                Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                                PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
                                NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                                        .setContentTitle("Signalr Name := " + p1 +" Msg:="+p2)
                                        .setTicker("Signalr Name := " + p1 +" Msg:="+p2)
                                        .setContentText("Signalr Name := " + p1 +" Msg:="+p2)
                                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                                        .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                                        .setOngoing(true);
                                NotificationManager notificationManager =
                                        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                                notificationManager.notify(0, notification.build());
                            }
                        }, String.class, String.class);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection is reconnected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        chat.invoke("Send", "Yogesh Says", "Magizhchi!").done(new Action<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void run(Void obj) throws Exception {
                                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
                                    public void run() {
                                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

                conn.closed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Log.d("close","close");
                        if (conn.getState().toString().equals("Disconnected"))
                        {
                            new reconnectPulling().execute();
                        }
                    }
                });
                conn.reconnected(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Log.e("reconnected","reconnected");
                        new reconnectPulling().execute();
                        chat.on("broadcastMessage", new SubscriptionHandler2<String, String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void run(final String p1, final String p2) {
                                Log.d("Signalr", "Name := " + p1 +" Msg:="+p2);
                            }
                        }, String.class, String.class);

                    }
                });
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ConnectionState connectionState, ConnectionState connectionState1) {
            if(connectionState1==ConnectionState.Connected){
                Log.d("connected","connected");
             //   configConnectFuture();
            }
        else if(connectionState1==ConnectionState.Disconnected){
                conn.disconnect();
                Log.d("disonncected","disconnected");
              new   reconnectPulling().execute();
            }
        else if(connectionState1==ConnectionState.Connecting){
                Log.d("connectingstate","connectingstate");
           ///     new reconnectPulling().execute();
            }
    }

    private class reconnectPulling extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                try {
                    if (conn.getState().toString() != "Connected") {
                        conn.disconnect();
                      configConnectFuture();
                        Log.d("reconnect", "Reconnect To Server...");
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    }
                    else {
                                 Log.d("connect","connectd");
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.interrupted();
                }

            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    private final ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                                       IBinder service) {
            // We've bound to SignalRService, cast the IBinder and get SignalRService instance
            SignalRService.LocalBinder binder = (SignalRService.LocalBinder) service;
            mService = binder.getService();
            mBound = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
            mBound = false;
        }
    };
}
```

While staying in this activity when internet available need to reconnect server how can i achieve this !!